# Difference between @click and v-on:click Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vue-directives

The questions should be enough clear.

But I can see that someone use:

```
<button @click="function()">press</button>
```

Someone use:

```
<button v-on:click="function()">press</button>
```

But really what is the difference between the two (if exists)

Answer (score 281, accepted):

There is no difference between the two, one is just a shorthand for the second.

> The v- prefix serves as a visual cue for identifying Vue-specific
> attributes in your templates. This is useful when you are using Vue.js
> to apply dynamic behavior to some existing markup, but can feel
> verbose for some frequently used directives. At the same time, the
> need for the v- prefix becomes less important when you are building an
> SPA where Vue.js manages every template.

```html
<!-- full syntax -->
<a v-on:click="doSomething"></a>
<!-- shorthand -->
<a @click="doSomething"></a>
```

Source: [official documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-on-Shorthand).

Comment: Is there Vue community preference towards @ or is it just JetBrains preference to complain about the use of v-on?

Comment: @KimmoHintikka Yes, there is somehow a preference toward the shortcut (@). The rule is included in `strongly-recommended` and `recommended` of the eslint-plugin-vue presets. https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/blob/master/docs/rules/v-on-style.md

Answer (score 112):

`v-bind` and `v-on` are two frequently used directives in vuejs html template.
So they provided a shorthand notation for the both of them as follows:

You can replace `v-on:` with `@`

```
v-on:click='someFunction'
```

as:

```
@click='someFunction'
```

Another example:

```
v-on:keyup='someKeyUpFunction'
```

as:

```
@keyup='someKeyUpFunction'
```

Similarly, `v-bind` with `:`

```
v-bind:href='var1'
```

Can be written as:

```
:href='var1'
```

Comment: @LorenzoBerti how about this answer. Did it helped you to understand more?

Comment: The answer does not explain anything, just gives examples 1/3 of which are inconsistent with the question asked. sorry.

Comment: v-bind and v-on are two frequently used directives in vuejs html template. So they provided a shorthand notation for the both of them 

I think this explains the question.
that is the reason provided in the cue js documentation as well :-)

Comment: The thing is the answer has been posted 4 months later with no links, no citation, and throwing in the colon-shorthand for v-bind, that can actually add to the confusion.

Comment: @JakubStrebeyko i dont know what you're btiching about but this is a pretty neat answer and also cleared my confusion regarding the plain colon which i  didn't know stood for v-bind.

Comment: If you want to use an argument in a function call, it still has to be a callable so use something like `@click="() => someFunction(argument)"`

Answer (score 3):

They may look a bit different from normal HTML, but : and @ are valid chars for attribute names and all Vue.js supported browsers can parse it correctly. In addition, they do not appear in the final rendered markup. The shorthand syntax is totally optional, but you will likely appreciate it when you learn more about its usage later.

Source: [official documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-on-Shorthand).

Answer (score 2):

#### Official source

The official Vue.js style guide recommends sticking with one version and keeping it consistent.

> Directive shorthands (: for v-bind:, @ for v-on: and # for v-slot) should be used **always** or **never**.

This rule is defined in the [Strongly Recommended](https://vuejs.org/style-guide/rules-strongly-recommended.html#quoted-attribute-values) section.

---

It can be enforced with `eslint` by using the `eslint-plugin-vue` plugin and setting the **vue/v-on-style** rule.

Default is set to shorthand.

```json
{
  "vue/v-on-style": ["error", "shorthand" | "longform"]
}
```

**Example**

```vue
<template>
  <!-- ✓ GOOD -->
  <div @click="foo"/>

  <!-- ✗ BAD -->
  <div v-on:click="foo"/>
</template>
```