# Vuetify - How to handle click event on <v-btn>?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm new to `vuetify` and `vue`, trying to figure out how to handle click event on `<v-btn>`. *(Using `vue 2.6.10` and `vuetify 2.0.0`)*

*(Surprised that didn't find a single code snippet that could work, after searching in both vuetify official document & via Google.)*

---

### Code

- Button

  `<v-btn color="primary" rounded @onclick.native="startQuiz">Start</v-btn>`
- Handler method from `methods` part of the containing component.

  ```
  startQuiz() {
    console.log('start');
    alert('start');
  }
  ```

After click the button, can't see console output from browser, neither did the alert pop-up.

In browser's vue plugin, under the `Events` sub tab, I can see following events:

> `click $emit by <VBtn>`

---

### Questions

- How to make the `startQuiz` method called when click the button?

---

### Update - Summary

I checked following link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45369553/difference-from-click-and-v-onclick-vuejs

Turns out it's just a shorthand for `v-on:click`, and `onclick` is from javascript, and invalid in vue's context.

Comment: That should be `@click="startQuiz"`.

Comment: @HusamIbrahim I tried that first, before append `.native`, neither worked.

Comment: Why do you think you need `.native`?

Comment: @user3483203 Refer to this link: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/35

Comment: Just to be sure. Did you try `@onclick="startQuiz"` or `@click="startQuiz"`?

Comment: @HusamIbrahim `@click` worked, thank you, didn't check it clearly. And `@click.xxx` seems also works, and `xxx` seems could be any value, e.g `@click.abc` will also work, Lol.

Comment: @EricWangyou should definitely look through the event modifiers to better understand them. `@click.xxx` is very useful to prevent the default action or stop propagation etc... https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers

Comment: Don't use `.native` modifier unless you're 100% certain that the `root element of the component broadcasts the event`

Comment: @TimWickstrom I have finished reading most part of event modifier, the `.once` modifier is especial useful here on the `Start` button, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to read [VueJS Events Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html), in there you'll get everything you need.
There's an example of the docs:

```
<div id="example-2">
  <!-- `greet` is the name of a method defined below -->
  <button v-on:click="greet">Greet</button>
</div>
```

```js
var example2 = new Vue({
  el: '#example-2',
  data: {
    name: 'Vue.js'
  },
  // define methods under the `methods` object
  methods: {
    greet: function (event) {
      // `this` inside methods points to the Vue instance
      alert('Hello ' + this.name + '!')
      // `event` is the native DOM event
      if (event) {
        alert(event.target.tagName)
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: The question is specifically related to Vuetify buttons.

Comment: Hi Pedro, the issue was about Vuetify, but the core was on a VueJs concept.

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way;

```
<v-btn color="primary" rounded @click.prevent="startQuiz">Start</v-btn>

methods:{
     startQuiz(){
           console.log('start')
     }
}
```