# Differentiate between user input and data change with vue element ui

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, element-ui

I am using vue element UI.

and on user input change I want to save data (something like autosave).

So far there is one event provided by element UI, that is "change" event.

But that is also calling when I assign value from backend, in that case data are already saved.

So how to detect whether value has come from user or from our binding (I know I can take flag in this case if there is no other better solution)?

```
<div id="app">
<template>
  <!-- `checked` should be true or false -->
  <el-checkbox v-model="checked" @change="changed">Option</el-checkbox>
</template>

var Main = {
    data() {
      return {
        checked: true
      };
    },methods: {
      changed(val) {
        alert('This should only change when user inputs, not when data is updated from code');

        setTimeout(function(){
          //Here alert should not appear as this is not manual input.
          this.checked = !this.checked;
        },5000);


      }
    }
  };
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

Here is a codepen

https://codepen.io/hnviradiya/pen/zYORGRR

Comment: please share some code to get the picture more clearer

Comment: seems, this is working in codepen. let me check on my code. I have updated code in question anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change event was working perfectly fine.

My mistake was (in code I had written, got answer when I wrote code for question which I took from element ui webpage when asked by @Boussadjra Brahim in comment) that I had bind it using (:) instead of (@).

So it was expecting `@change` and I had provided `:change`.

For more details.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46748348/9263418

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1

The `@input` event should work well for that case. Small diference is, that it triggeres at each key down.

### Solution 2

You could use `Vue.nextTick`

Before setting the value from backend in code, you could set a flag `this.isSettingValue = true`. Then you set the value and call `Vue.nextTick(() => { this.isSettingValue = false });`

Now you can avoid autosaving by checking `this.isSettingValue == true`.
Using `Vue.nextTick` ensures that the flag isn't set back to false until after the asynchronous data update completes.

[Vue.nextTick( [callback, context] )](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick)

Comment: @input is only available in text controls. checkbox and others don't have that event. :( https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/checkbox

Comment: Did not know you have a checkbox, since you did not provie code examples. Did you try Vue.nextTick?

Comment: ya, that nextTick as mentioned in question can be solution. just wanted to discover if there is better way than having flag.